# Complete list of Mario Kart 7 habit titles

Tags: mario-kart-7

In the recently released Nintendo title, *Mario Kart 7,* there is a feature new to the series that allows the game to track your performance during gameplay against bots and other players online. Based upon these data, your racer will be assigned a title visible in the in-game Mario Kart Channel in the lower-right corner of the screen and to other racers who meet you over Street- or SpotPass. These titles, presumably, are then used to determine the skill and attributes of your AI Mii in others' games when playing offline.

This system appears to track the player's most prominent habits over the last several races (and battles?), assigning titles such as "Rookie," "Banana Blitzer," "Shell Shark," Bob-omb Ace," "Model Driver," "Safe Driver," "Star Driver," and more. However, a complete list of these titles and their exact requirements does not seem to be easily findable, at least to my perusal of the sparse paper manual, digital manual, and results from Google queries.

Can anyone provide a complete list of these titles along with their requirements? If an official list does not exist, this seems to the task of experimentation or reverse-engineering of the game, neither of which I have the immediate time, skill, or tools to perform.

Comment: I have right now the "Comeback Kid" habit title. I guess thats because i've been very persistent in recent online matches, like people knowcking me back from 1st to 5th or 6th place and then coming back to 1st or 2nd. And i've been hitting back people that hit me before.

Answer (score 6):

So far, I've gotten:

- Dolphin (good in water?)
- Bomb omb ace
- Aviator (good flyer)
- Shell Shark
- Star Racer
- Quick Starter (Boost at beginning)
- Comeback Kid
- Rookie
- Banana Blitzer
- Rowdy Racer (?)
- Boost Jumper
- Drift Wizard
- Pro Defender

Comment: I've only gotten:
Rookie
Aviator
Aerialist And I have currently Comeback King (I;m not sure if it's different from kid)

Comment: [This post](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/997822-mario-kart-7/62110976) on the GameFAQs board lists some more titles, but doesn't seem to be comprehensive either.